# Finding Sentinel-1 data from the hub

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, sentinel-1

Can somebody please tell me how to download data from specific locations on the [sentinel-1 data hub](https://scihub.esa.int/)?

I cannot seem to get the geospatial search function to work...

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? When you search, does it find no data, or is the problem somewhere else in the process?

Comment: For example if I use the map selection box to zoom in on Bangladesh and then search for available products it returns data from beyond the bounding  box from all over the world. No way to find Bangladesh specific info.

Answer (score 1):

When you draw the selection box, does the selected area become a orange colour? Otherwise, you can also try to not use the map, and just make your search directly in the 'Request done:' field. In there you write the following: 
( footprint:"Intersects(POLYGON((
87.782509765619 21.546011713331,
91.671669921869 21.546011713331,
91.671669921869 24.797631297596,
87.782509765619 24.797631297596,
87.782509765619 21.546011713331)))" )

In the current form, the search box covers most of Bangladesh, but you can change it by changing the coordinates. The form is Lower-Left, Upper-Left, Upper-Right, Lower-Right, Lower-Left.

Answer (score 0):

When you do your search, 25 (by default) images are listed. They are drawn on the map so you can see the extent of the images. You may need to zoom out to see the extent of those images.

If there are no green or red shaded boxes over the extent that you are interested in, then there are no images for you IN THAT LIST OF 25. Click on the > to see the next page and continue until you find what you are looking for.

When you see a red or green shaded box, click on it, and the list (of 25) moves to show you the item you have selected. From there you can see the options of adding to your cart or downloading immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Python API for this. Especailly if you wish to download a lot of data.

Please see the code:

```
#First, import this library (sentinelsat)
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt

#Enter your username and password
api = SentinelAPI("USER", "PASSWORD", "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus")

#Define the path to your AOI - Must be a Geojson shapefile
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson(r"path/to/AOI.geojson"))
#Define the products you need - Here you will be looking for Ground Range detected products, with a Descending orbit direction from 01/05/2019 to 01/06/2019 
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20190501','20190601'),
                     producttype = 'GRD',
                     orbitdirection='DESCENDING')
#Download all products 
api.download_all(products)
```

FYI, if you're looking for countrywide data, split the AOI up into smaller shapefiles (Either for the Sentinelsat Python AOI, or on the Sci-hub as i had this issue where it returned no results if my AOI was too large.

Have a read of this for more info:
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/sentinelsat/master/sentinelsat.pdf

Thanks,

Comment: Was this of use?